# Downloading GPdatafile from ArcGIS Server?

Tags: arcgis-10.2, arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, geoprocessing-service, download

I want to download a GPdataFile from a GIS server.

In fact, I am using the PrintTask Service, which generates my map instance in various formats.

I have the url of the specific file on the sever, and I want to force the browser to download it immediately after the PrintTask callback finishes, as if I had content disposition enabled.

Which service could I use to fetch that file from the server?

I am using ArcGIS Server 10.2.2.

Answer (score 1):

This [tutorial here](http://server.arcgis.com/en/server/latest/publish-services/windows/gp-service-example-basic-high-quality-webmap-printing.htm) I believe does exactly what you want. (Scroll to the bottom)

Or, heres some pointed JavaScript code which I use to return a link to a `<div><span>` element that populates with a hyperlink.

```
 function go() {  

      var inputText = dojo.byId('inText').value;
      var params = {'Input_Text': inputText };
      gp_R.submitJob(params, gpJobComplete, gpJobStatus, function(error){
          alert(error);          
       });
    }   

    function gpJobComplete(jobInfo) {  

      if(jobInfo.jobStatus == "esriJobFailed") {                            
        dojo.byId('downURL').innerHTML = "Failed to generate text file";        
       }    
       else if (jobInfo.jobStatus == "esriJobSucceeded") {          
            gp_R.getResultData(jobInfo.jobId,"Output_Text_File", downloadFile);         
      }
    }       

    function downloadFile(outputFile) {  

       var theurl = outputFile.value.url;  
       dojo.byId('downURL').innerHTML = "<a href='"+ theurl + "'>Download File (right-click, save-as)</a>";  
    }
```

....

Comment: thanks for you extensive answer. However I think that it is not what I want. I want the document to be directly downloaded without having to open any link. I want the "save as" popup to open immediately after the PrintTask  has finished, and automatically download the file from the known location of the arcgis server. Since The PrintTask does not have that capability, I am seeking for an another service that could reach that file via the url and open the save as popup. In other words when the user clicks download as PNG he will then have to choose where to store it locally.

Comment: Once the file is "ready", you want the "save-as" to popup in the users face. At its core, this is a HTML/JavaScript or maybe even PHP question. This really has nothing to do with the GP Service. You might have better luck on stackoverflow. Or give this a read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/156686/how-to-start-automatic-download-of-a-file-in-internet-explorer

Answer (score 0):

I guess it is not exactly what you asked for, but I wanted to do something similar and I ended up opening a new window with the link I get from the server.

After you get the answer from the server open the window:

```
window.open(url);
```

The user can now either save the map or discard it.

Comment: it depends. If You extract it as image , it is not that nice to have to right click - download.

Comment: You're right. I chose to get the map as PDF and it works smooth when the user has a pdf viewer for the browser.

Comment: I used a solution from [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17527713/force-browser-to-download-image-files-on-click) and it seems to be working for me. Try the following where 'url' is the your image link:
`var link = document.createElement('a');
link.href = url;
link.download = 'filename.png';
document.body.appendChild(link);
link.click();`